# Repeated regex/PCRE named capturing groups with a match in front

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

I'm trying to parse sendmail logs. These come split - with the 'to' and 'from' on different lines. I want to match the 'to' in order to establish that the line we're looking at is a 'to' line then catch as many email addresses as are present. There are many requests for help similar to this, but none (that I've found and I promise I have been looking!) that quite fit the same scenario.

I have tried working from several solutions on Stack Overflow without success. The issue is that the 'to=' is not optional, it is a requirement. Is this possible the PCRE regex?

Regex thus far (that only matches the first email address):

```
to\=((\<)?(?P<to>.+?\@.+?)(\>)?\,)
```

Example line:

```
Jul 16 13:35:05 mailserver sendmail[30892]: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: to=user1@example.derp,user2@example.derp,user3@example.derp, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=smtp, pri=91785, relay=relay.example.derp [1.2.3.4], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx@mailserver.derp> Queued mail for delivery)
```

Ideally the matching after the 'to\=' would then match as many email address as are present, not just the first. If there is an answer to this out there that would work that I have missed/been unable to bend to my scenario - apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the `\G` anchor to get iterative matches asserting the position at the end of the previous match and capture the email address in a capturing group.

```
(?:to=|\G(?!^))([^,\s@]+@[^@,\s]+),
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `to=` match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^,\s@]+@[^@,\s]+` Negated character class, match any char other than a comma, @ or whitespace with matching an `@` inbetween
- `),` Close group 1 and match comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9XoLsW/1)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I can't test right now due to being on training!

Comment: Some of the lines seem to have <> wrapped around the email address, i.e. <email@server.com>, which breaks the above. Would this be an acceptable fix: (?:to=|\G(?!^))(<?)(?P<to>[^,\s@]+@[^@,\s]+?)(>)?,

Comment: This seems good: ,\s*delay=.+|(?<=to=|,),?(<)?(?<to>[^@,=]+@[^<>\,]+)

Comment: You could do it like that and you can also omit the capturing group so just use `<?` and `>?`. Note that it will also match the email if there is only < or > present as both are optional.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using:

```
,\s*delay=.+|(?<=to=|,),?(<)?(?<to>[^@,=]+@[^<>\,]+)
```

It won't be perfect, but it works for me.